# In R, how can I create a column that displays what percentile of the data is a value in a different column

Tags: r, quantile, percentile

So my data looks like this, with # of rows = 6000 approx.

```
        pidp      avgy06
    1 68160489 20182.36849
    2 68575973 13845.49024
    3 69180553    35.61806
    4 69786365 13117.26465
    5 69815605 15791.40283
    6 69833973 10327.94531
```

I would like to know if there's a way to apply the `quantile()` function, so as to add another column that gives me what percentile of the data is each value of `avgy06`. For example, this is the 100 percentiles of `avgy06`:

```
        0%         1%         2%         3%         4%         5%         6%         7%         8%         9%        10% 
    0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000   189.0078 
       11%        12%        13%        14%        15%        16%        17%        18%        19%        20%        21% 
  790.2671  1505.4875  2364.4903  2900.0230  3441.0689  3680.2787  4246.6805  4595.0131  4704.8372  4904.6381  5217.9201 
       22%        23%        24%        25%        26%        27%        28%        29%        30%        31%        32% 
 5421.2263  5621.4581  6166.7022  6673.1660  6851.0085  7261.1324  7588.7569  7947.6250  8292.3789  8606.2774  8938.2232 
       33%        34%        35%        36%        37%        38%        39%        40%        41%        42%        43% 
 9286.9695  9665.7901  9885.2171 10035.7984 10280.0676 10423.1376 10633.2589 10886.2913 11205.7540 11411.0259 11581.6681 
       44%        45%        46%        47%        48%        49%        50%        51%        52%        53%        54% 
11763.5549 11926.4006 12210.2935 12434.3433 12581.4526 12781.9956 13135.6904 13305.6350 13666.1352 13814.4657 14046.4000 
       55%        56%        57%        58%        59%        60%        61%        62%        63%        64%        65% 
14258.2219 14431.6258 14631.6608 14940.7309 15168.2559 15385.1055 15583.7370 15757.0793 15906.4169 16094.3642 16448.5898 
       66%        67%        68%        69%        70%        71%        72%        73%        74%        75%        76% 
16683.5195 16817.0613 17049.2498 17361.5975 17663.5911 18004.6763 18309.8879 18614.3184 18871.4102 19220.2478 19529.0051 
       77%        78%        79%        80%        81%        82%        83%        84%        85%        86%        87% 
19962.8668 20249.0984 20526.2794 20690.6686 20896.2913 21135.7998 21396.8414 21763.6818 22070.5915 22494.2696 23000.0000 
       88%        89%        90%        91%        92%        93%        94%        95%        96%        97%        98% 
23486.0340 24206.6486 25106.3743 26261.0410 26593.7715 27402.7684 28079.6456 28910.4655 30315.5573 32447.8075 39225.6094 
       99%       100% 
41759.9540 57456.0758
```

I would like an extra column in my dataframe that reads the value of `avgy06` and returns to what percentile of the data does such value correspond to (e.g 75th, 63th...). If there's another way without using the `quantile()` function, let me know.

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you mean adding a column for each percentile you want?

Comment: I mean adding a single column that displays to what percentile of the data does each row of avgy06 corresponds to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use another dataset for illustration. What you're looking for is the *empirical cumulative distribution function* or [`ecdf`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/ecdf).

```
data(iris) #data for illustration
data_ecdf <- ecdf(iris[, 'Sepal.Length'])
iris[, 'Sepal.Length.Percentile'] <- data_ecdf(iris[, 'Sepal.Length'])
head(iris)
# Output:
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Length.Percentile
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa              0.27333333
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa              0.14666667
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa              0.07333333
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa              0.06000000
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa              0.21333333
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa              0.34666667
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Saved me a lot of frustration. Thanks again

Comment: I am glad i could help out. :-) With danger of selfish-selfpromotion, if this did answer your question, remember to mark it as the answer to your question. This will make it more visible to others in the future, while giving 15 hard-earned points to the author of the answer, further motivating them to spent time answering questions in the future. :-)